# Buildozer can't find Cython

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, cython, buildozer, kali-linux

When I lauch `buildozer -v android debug` or `buildozer android debug`

Buildozer returns: `Cython (cython) not found, please install it.`

So I try to install Cython with `sudo pip3 install Cython` but it returns that `Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.29.21)`

What I have to do ?

Comment: It's probably indicating that cython is not installed in whatever python environment you are running buildozer from.

Comment: So how can I installed in the good python environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to create an environment to do this